# MUI styles not working when install my react storybook library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, storybook

I have created a new storybook library using react with MUI material, but problem is that, i am using MUI custom theme and all MUI styles is working in my storyboook library and publish this storybook on gitlab and install in my new react app and when i am using button in my new react app styles not working which is define in my react storybook library.

pls chk these reference for my storybook library:  http://ec2-15-207-106-67.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4873/-/web/detail/@tyke-investor/ui-library

install in my new app this command:  npm install @tyke-investor/ui-library

storybook library button styles and preview:
[image]

using storybook library in new app button styles and preview:
[image]

please suggest what is the problem in my new app

I am trying this but my storybook styles not apply on button.
[image]

Comment: I'm also pretty interested in this question. I'm basically having the very same issue and to bypass it I had to export my theme as part of my library, import it on my react app and apply it with <ThemeProvider />. A very hacky way of making it work :(

Comment: Thanks dear its working now

Comment: How did you make it work? Did you find a proper solution for it? It'd be nice to know how you ended up making it work.